# How to AutoUpdate as each day passes a conditional format based on date?

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting, auto-update

I'm new to writing VBA code but have managed to struggle along for the past couple of weeks.

I have created a code for a worksheet change event that highlights certain dates input within particular windows like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Dim icolor As Integer 
    Dim cell As Range 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C3:T65")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 
    For Each cell In Target 
        icolor = 0 
        Select Case cell 
        Case "": icolor = 2 
        Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3 
        Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 6 
        Case Is > Date + 60: icolor = 2 
        End Select 
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor 
    Next cell 
End Sub
```

It works flawlessly. However, I need the spreadsheet to basically update the highlighting each day. IE: If Date + 61 is not highlighted today, it will be highlighted tomorrow because it fits the window as Date + 60. I suspect that a simple "worksheet change event" can't do this (because it requires user input).

I have tried tweaking this into a worksheet activate code, to potentially update highlights when the document is opened (and I'm trying to avoid workbook open because I will have multiple sheets doing different things), but I can't get it to work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks ahead of time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If Intersect(Target, Range("C3:T65")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each cell In Target
        icolor = 0
        Select Case cell
            Case "": icolor = 2    
            Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
            Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 6
            Case Is > Date + 60: icolor = 2            
        End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Target` parameter passed to Worksheet_activate, so you can't use the `Intersect()` test. You just need to loop over your range directly

```
For Each cell In Me.Range("C3:T65").Cells
    'check value
Next cell
```

Best approach here would be to split the hiliting logic into a separate Sub and just call that from your event handlers:

EDIT: added workbook_open

```
'in ThisWorkbook module
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Sheet1.CheckData Sheet1.Range("C3:T65")
End Sub

'in sheet code module
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    CheckData Me.Range("C3:T65")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    CheckData Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:T65"))
End Sub

Sub CheckData(rng As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        icolor = 0
        Select Case cell
            Case "": icolor = 2
            Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
            Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 6
            Case Is > Date + 60: icolor = 2
        End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: When VBA is running in a sheet code module (or any instance of a Class), `Me` refers to the sheet to which that module is attached. You should not need to change it to (eg) `Sheet1`. In fact, it's more robust to leave it as `Me`: then if you change the sheet's code name nothing will break...

Comment: I've updated the code. Is there any way I can test whether it properly updates without having to wait until tomorrow?

I've forced dates to be improperly (manually) highlighted and upon opening/closing they remain wrongly highlighted. I've also forced changing my system date on the computer which hasn't changed anything as well.

Comment: Just set the color of all the cells in the checked range to "none" and then switch between sheets.  Switching back should trigger the macro and color all the cells appropriately.

Comment: Just to add - if the worksheet is active when the workbook is open, then the worksheet_activate event won't be triggered: you will need to put some code in the `ThisWorkbook` module to handle that: use the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: I tried to no avail: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub`

Comment: Disregard that last comment. I saw you changed the code above. It works! Thank you very much for helping me to understand all of this!